# Как сделать адаптивное окно в WPF?

Tags: wpf, адаптивность

Начальное окно, при запуске, подгружает три фрэйма. Первый и третий фрэйм остаются неизменными, во втором будет обновляться весь контент.

Как сделать, чтобы второй фрэйм увеличивал высоту окна в зависимости от своего контента и все элементы отображались целиком?

[image]

Comment: Используйте свойство SizeToContent у окна. Не уверен, что это будет хорошо работать с Frame, но Frame вообще подход не очень хороший, обычно удобнее работать с ContentControl

Comment: Можно. Можно сделать все что угодно